# Measurements of dxf converted to svf file are wrong on mobile

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

I have discovered what I think may be a bug with the autodesk forge viewer. Using the free online viewer available on the autodesk website, I have tested a known measurement on different devices and get different results depending on what I use. On PC, I get 150mm, on my phone I get ~ 148 mm. I tested with the free online tool in order to rule out the possibility that the issue was with the implementation of my viewer on my website. The issue occurs in both environments. The real measurement is supposed to be 150.4 mm. And yes, both measurement lines are straight. [Here is a picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vCiz.png)

The question is, is this a bug? Are measurements expected to differ depending on what device you use? Is this why the callibrate tool exists? I can't use the calibrate tool for this issue because it is not realistic to expect every file to have defined measurement artificats to calibrate with...

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**: The measurements between objects are not wrong. We have discovered that the grid lines shift on mobile devices. Unsure why this is the case, but when you measure from object A to object B the distance is correct across all devices. On mobile, when you measure from object A to gridline, or gridline to object B, the distances are incorrect. Therefore, on mobile devices the gridline is shifted and so far we have not any idea why! And on PC, the gridlines do not shift incorrectly!